# Copying data from excel spreadsheet into list with python

Tags: python, excel

I'm trying to copy data from particular cells in an excel spreadsheet to a list. I would like to do some simple calculations on the data after, however I cannot seem to get the data to append into a list. I get an error saying "AttributeError: 'list' object attribute 'insert' is read-only"

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
Millar_sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Millar')

for rowOfCellObjects in Millar_sheet['N2':'AA2']: 
    for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
        if cellObj.value != None:
         print(cellObj.coordinate, cellObj.value)
    print('--- END OF ROW ---')

for rowOfCellObjects in Millar_sheet['N2':'AA2']:
    for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
        if cellObj.value != None:
         print(cellObj.coordinate, cellObj.value)
         client.append = (cellObj.value)
    print('--- END OF ROW ---')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't append to a list in python by saying `client.append() = xyz`

Try the following

```
client.append(cellObj.value)
```

Comment: Also worth noting the `client` name hasn't been assigned yet, so this will probably error unless OP does `client = []` ahead of the `for` loop.